# Suppose use the substitution $u = 2x + 3$ to evaluate the definite integral

Tags: integration

Suppose use the substitution $u = 2x + 3$ to evaluate the definite integral

"integrate $\frac{1}{2x+3}$ from $x = 0$ to $1$" I knew the answer is integrate $\frac{1}{2u}$ from $u = 3$ to $5$

How to get the expressions after performing the substitution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that you need to integrate $\frac{1}{2u}$. You have to substitute $du$ for the variable of integration, using the equation $\dfrac{1}{2}du =dx$. Also, the integral is from $3$ to $5$, as you correctly pointed out. Evaluating $\displaystyle\int_3^5 \frac{1}{2u}du$ gives $\dfrac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)$.